# Automate data from multiple csv files and linear regression

Tags: python, loops, plot, regression, equation

(NB: I'm very new to python and this is my first post on Stack Overflow!)

I have a directory that has multiple .csv files, each with a column of Force and a column of Displacement data. I want to perform the same linear regression plot function to each of them without having to change the file name within the .py file. (Ideally I would like each equation to be an output, but for now I'm happy with multiple plots!)

So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

values = pd.read_csv('RawData_1.csv')

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = 
stats.linregress(values['Displacement'],values['Force'])

ax = sns.regplot(x="Displacement", y="Force", data=values, color='b', 
line_kws={'label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope,intercept)})

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I've tried implementing lines from other posts but having no luck. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `glob.glob()` to get the contents of the directory as a list, then use a for loop to create a figure for each file:

```
import glob
# assuming you want to go ove the current working directory
files = glob.glob('RawData*.csv')
for f in files:
    values = pd.read_csv(f)

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = 
    stats.linregress(values['Displacement'],values['Force'])

    ax = sns.regplot(x="Displacement", y="Force", data=values, color='b', 

    line_kws={'label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope,intercept)})

    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It would be better to use `glob.glob("*.csv")` to avoid non-CSV files.

Comment: I didn't know glob before, thanks for the suggestion - it does simplify things

Comment: That works thank you! Can I ask what the meaning behind the "f" in "for f in files" and "...read_csv(f)" is?

Comment: When you iterate over a list, you name the element you're currently working on. so in our case what python does is: `f = files[0]` then it runs the loop's body with f being the first element. then `f = files[1]` and runs the loop's body again with f being the second. you can replace f with anything (e.g. `for element in files`) just don't forget to replace all occurrences of f in the loop's body.
You can read more about for loops here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop